# How to Add a Sub Menu Page to a Custom Post Type?

Tags: custom-post-types, add-submenu-page

I am trying to create a sub-menu under a Custom Post Type I have named Portfolios.

When I change `add_submenu_page()` to `add_options_page()`, it correctly shows a new link under the Settings menu, but it doesn't show under the Portfolios menu.

What am I doing wrong?

Below is my code snippet;

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'mt_add_pages' );

function mt_add_pages() {
    add_submenu_page(
        __( 'portfolios', 'menu-test' ),
        __( 'Test Settings', 'menu-test' ),
        'manage_options',
        'testsettings',
        'mt_settings_page'
    );

    function mt_settings_page() {
        echo "<h2>" . __( 'Test Settings', 'menu-test' ) . "</h2>";
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you are passing incorrent parent slug, i.e portfolios. check it again... inplace of portfolios pass the slug of your custom post type..

Answer (score 43):

[`add_options_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_options_page/) automatically adds it underneath settings, however [`add_submenu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/) gives you control as to where you want it to show up.

Try something like this:

```
add_submenu_page(
    'edit.php?post_type=portfolios',
    __( 'Test Settings', 'menu-test' ),
    __( 'Test Settings', 'menu-test' ),
    'manage_options',
    'testsettings',
    'mt_settings_page'
);
```

Comment: Your code won't work unless, you're missing an third argument of `menu_title`. See the codex

Answer (score 7):

To expand on @Jai example...

### My Settings

```
$postType = 'foo';
$categoryType = 'bar';
```

### Custom Post Type

```
            $args = array(
                    'labels'             => array('name'=>$postType, ...),
                    'rewrite'            => array('slug' => 'all-'.$postType),
                    'taxonomies'         => array($categoryType)
            );

register_post_type( 'foo', $args );
```

### Custom Category Taxonomy

```
            $args = array(
                    'labels'            => array( 'name' => _x( $categoryType, 'taxonomy general name' )),
                    'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => $categoryType ),
            );

register_taxonomy( $categoryType, array( $postType ), $args );
```

### Add Categories as submenu items

```
    $wp_term = get_categories( 'taxonomy='.$categoryType.'&type='.$postType ); 
    if ( $wp_term ) {
        foreach ( $wp_term as $term ) {
            // add_submenu_page( string $parent_slug, string $page_title, string $menu_title, string $capability, string $menu_slug,                                                  callable $function = '' )
            add_submenu_page(    'edit.php?post_type='.$postType,      $term->name,        $term->name,        'manage_options',   'edit.php?post_type='.$postType.'&'.$categoryType.'='.$term->slug, ''); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type='.$this->plugin->posttype, __('Settings', $this->plugin->name), __('Settings', $this->plugin->name), 'manage_options', $this->plugin->name, array(&$this, 'adminPanel'));
```

there is admin panel is a callback function name.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more?

Answer (score 4):

```php
/**
* Adds a submenu page under a custom post type parent.
*/
function books_register_ref_page() {
    add_submenu_page(
        'edit.php?post_type=book',
        __( 'Books Shortcode Reference', 'textdomain' ),
        __( 'Shortcode Reference', 'textdomain' ),
        'manage_options',
        'books-shortcode-ref',
        'books_ref_page_callback'
    );
}

/**
* Display callback for the submenu page.
*/
function books_ref_page_callback() { 
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1><?php _e( 'Books Shortcode Reference', 'textdomain' ); ?></h1>
        <p><?php _e( 'Helpful stuff here', 'textdomain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

[Link to Source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/#comment-1261) , Author: Christina Blust