# Subset of Custom Post Type From Admin Menu Based on Meta Data

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu

I understand I can associate CPTs in submenus like so: [Is It Possible To Add Custom Post Type Menu As Another Custom Post Type Sub Menu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110562/is-it-possible-to-add-custom-post-type-menu-as-another-custom-post-type-sub-menu)

However, my question is if I have ***one*** CPT, let's say for a ECommerce type of post type, so it would be ***Orders*** as the post type and I have orders with different meta information in their post_meta such as *approved*, *pending*, *denied*, etc. can I have submenus which load an admin table using `WP_List_Table` of a subset of the custom post type, that is based on their meta data.

So the admin menu looks like

```
-Orders CPT (Show All Orders in List)
--Approved Orders (Show only Approved Orders in List)
--Denied Orders (Show only Denied Orders in List)

etc.
```

The reason I am asking is because at first I was doing `add_menu()` or `add_submenu()` with a custom callback to generate the HTML, but then I realized this was unnecessary as I was ending up recreating the default `WP_List_Table`, but I don't want multiple CPTs when they are all really subsets of the same CPT differentiated by meta-data... is this possible or should I do different CPTs somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add two custom links to your CPT submenu, related:

[How to Add a Sub Menu Page to a Custom Post Type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63202/how-to-add-a-sub-menu-page-to-a-custom-post-type)

The callback function of these submenu pages could then display your subset of custom post types.

Comment: Yes but, I'm aware of this callback, my problem is I don't want to have to recreate the list of posts that fall under the CPT, I want the default display/view but only of the subset of CPTs with certain meta data.

Comment: In this case, why not just extend the filter functionality of your CPT admin screen? As an entry point, you could use this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/212527/129367

Comment: Yes thank you, this is a good idea but I am still wondering if my desired way is possible for ease of use for my end-users.

Comment: Since you want a combination of both a new submenu item and a custom fields filter, you might be able to create a submenu item with a custom link that reflects the filter, ie. `post_type=orders&filter_action=approved`.