# How to add custom settings to the menu of custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, options, settings-api, page-specific-settings

Not sure if this has been asked before. But how can we add custom settings to the menu of custom post types? Or add custom fields for an entire post type and you can edit them? For example:

[image]

This is my code for registering the custom post type:

```
<?php
// Creates Events Custom Post Type: connect.
function connect_init() {
    $args = [
        'labels' => [
            'name' => __('Connect (Pages)'),
            'singular_name' => __('Connect'),
            'all_items' => 'All Connects'
        ],
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => [
            'slug' => 'connects',
            'with_front' => true
        ],
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-star-filled',
        'supports' => [
            'title',
            'editor',
            'comments',
            'revisions',
            'thumbnail',
            'author',
            'page-attributes',
        ],
    ];
    register_post_type('connect', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'connect_init');

add_action('init', 'create_connect_categories');
function create_connect_categories() {
    $args = [
        'label' => __('Categories'),
        'has_archive' =>  true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => [
            'slug' => 'connects',
            'with_front' => true
        ],
    ];
    $postTypes = ['connect'];
    $taxonomy = 'connect-category';
    register_taxonomy($taxonomy, $postTypes, $args);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of custom settings? Are you just trying to add a submenu item under your CPT menu? As for the custom fields, you can just add `custom-fields` to the `supports` array of your post type args, and then the default [Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/support/article/custom-fields/) meta box would appear on the post editing screen for your CPT.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/76182/45202